# angularfontawesome not import

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GsCD.png)

install by this ---npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome
in app module import this -- AngularFontAwesomeModule

Answer (score 5):

In angular 9 IVy is by default true so change this to false
In tsconfig.app.json file add this
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }

after that go to the node_module folder and search angular font awesome 
go to the dist folder in that open file angular-font-awesome.js file and change the name of Renderer to Renderer2
Because in updated angular it support Renderer2

Comment: Ivy is one of the reasons why to upgrade to newer version of Angular (starting with v9), plainly disabling it is not just a hack, it's also quite bad solution.

Comment: I am working on Angular 11.2, The above changes Renderer to Renderer2 in angular-font-awesone is works perfectly!!!   Appreciated your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I had used it with angular 8,9 and it was so good.

You just need to read the document and follow.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js 1448:12-20
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
 it give this error

Answer (score 0):

To install font-awesome in your project, please follow below steps

1) **npm install font-awesome**

2) Set the font-awesome.css path in Angular.json files "**styles**" array. 
   Commonly it is like this **"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"**

3) Make sure you define font-awesome path before style.scss path and after bootstrap css path

Comment: i want angularfornawesome not only fontawesome

Comment: @Avinash both are same I guess, I am using font-awesome in my angular projects and its working completely fine

Comment: I agree with @Arjun, I did the same. Just import "FontAwesomeModule".
Follow his steps and you will be good to go.

Comment: it give this error ----- ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js 1448:12-20
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'